# Connect-MsolService not working after upgrade System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt to version 5.3

Tags: c#, powershell, dll, jwt, office365

I have a C# application that calls Connect-MsolService in Runspace pipeline. It was working until I added BountyCastle to my project and upgraded the dll System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt to 5.3.

Now when the program calls Connect-MsolService, the following errors happens:

Could not load type 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityToken' from assembly 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt, Version=5.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

I set up a new project calling Connect-MsolService just to test this issue. I have System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 5.3 installed in the new project and it works fine. Using VS debug I can see that an older version of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 4.00.xx was loaded despite that v5.3 is installed and referenced.

Can someone help explaining this and eventually how to load the older version in my original application so it can work too? Thanks!

Comment: I added bountyCastle method calls to the new project and now I see both v5.3 and v4.0 are loaded and the new project still works fine.